# Meaning of this number function with different number values in if blocks

Tags: javascript, numbers, byte

Wondering what this `encode_number` function means, all of the different numbers. Specifically, I know that `32768` is for 16 bits (`Math.pow(2, 16) / 2`), and that the last `else` block is (from source code comments) a 32 bit number. But I don't understand where these numbers are coming from: `107, 139, 108, 1131, 247, 251, 28, 29`. Would like to know what the meaning of this function is. From [here](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/blob/637856c9f5a36f67ffd2afdc53cc46dff46c0f3e/src/types.js#L234).

```
function encode_number(v) {
  if (v >= -107 && v <= 107) {
    return [v + 139]
  } else if (v >= 108 && v <= 1131) {
      v = v - 108
    return [(v >> 8) + 247, v & 0xFF]
  } else if (v >= -1131 && v <= -108) {
      v = -v - 108
    return [(v >> 8) + 251, v & 0xFF]
  } else if (v >= -32768 && v <= 32767) {
    // encode_number16
    return [28, (v >> 8) & 0xFF, v & 0xFF]
  } else {
    // encode_number32
    return [29, (v >> 24) & 0xFF, (v >> 16) & 0xFF, (v >> 8) & 0xFF, v & 0xFF]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was simple:

- By using the `blame` view of that linked source code, you come across the [commit that introduced these lines](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/commit/74f61a30639dc4e92bf94e06f800c461785442fa). The commit message was: "Add CFF table encoding."
- By searching for CFF and 107, you find an explanation of that [CFF dictionary format](https://github.com/Pomax/the-cff-table/blob/master/README.md#dict-data)

So, this function is used to encode something for that "Compact Font Format" which kind of belongs to OpenType. But what that actually *means* is out of my knowledge ;)